# Update multiple records based on 1 record meeting a criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause, correlated-subquery

I am trying to Select all records from a dataset where 1 of the records meets a criteria. I have a table of data that contain the hours worked by a person by day. I need to select all the records for a person for that week, if one record within that week has the 'logged' flag set to 'N'. Here's a data example:

t_hours:

```
Name  Week  Weekday  Hours  Logged
===============================
Jim   1     Mon      8       Y
Jim   1     Wed      8       Y
Jim   1     Fri      8       Y
Jim   2     Mon      8       Y
Jim   2     Wed      8       Y
Bill  1     Mon      8       N
Bill  1     Tue      8       Y
Bill  1     Wed      8       Y
Bill  1     Thu      8       Y
Bill  2     Mon      8       Y
Bill  2     Tue      8       Y
```

I want to write a query that will update all the records for a persons workweek to Logged='N', if they have one day where Logged='N'. But I can't figure out how to even select the records. Here are the records that I want to update:

```
Name  Week  Weekday  Hours  Logged
===============================
Bill  1     Mon      8       N
Bill  1     Tue      8       Y
Bill  1     Wed      8       Y
Bill  1     Thu      8       Y
```

I have tried a normal select, but can't figure out how to have two correlated subqueries in the where clause:

```
SELECT * FROM t_hours
WHERE (Name = (SELECT t1.Name FROM t_hours t1 
               where t1.Name = t2.Name and t1.Week = t2.Week and 
               t1.Logged = 'N') and
       Week = (SELECT t2.Week FROM t_hours t2 
               where t1.Name = t2.Name and t1.Week = t2.Week and 
               t2.Logged = 'N')
```

but this doesn't work, any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return data:

```
 SELECT *
FROM   t_hours t1
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM   t_hours t2
               WHERE  t1.NAME = t2.NAME
                      AND t1.week = t2.week
                      AND t2.logged = 'N');
```

Update data:

```
 UPDATE t_hours
SET    logged = 'N'
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM   t_hours t2
               WHERE  t1.NAME = t2.NAME
                      AND t1.week = t2.week
                      AND t2.logged = 'N');
```

If the data set is large enough, you could group by name, week, and logged type.

Comment: Thanks! This works for what I needed! Nice and Clean, marking as answered

Answer (score 1):

You can use an updatable CTE:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*,
             min(logged) over (partition by name, week) as min_logged
      from t
     )
update toupdate
    set logged = min_logged
    where min_logged = 'N' and min_logged <> logged;
```

The `min(logged)` expression will return `'N'` if any of the `logged` values are `'N'` (and the rest if any are `'Y'`) for the person/week.

Comment: This is a really clean answer, Gordon. Does min_logged only work because there's two options, e.g. N/Y, or would it still work if there were additional values? I'm assuming that it only works if the values are in ascending/descending order, respectively.

Comment: @SeanBrookins . . . `min()` is a convenience in this case because it takes on two values.  A slight variation can be used if there are more values, depending on the circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

try like below-using exists

```
select t1.* from table_name t1
where exists( select 1 from table_name t2 where t1.week=t2.week
                                          and t2.logged='N' and t1.name=t2.name
             )
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
   Update table set Logged='N' where
      Exists (Select 1 from(Select 
        Name,Workweek group by Name, 
       Workweek having count(Logged='N')
        >=1)t1 where Name=t1.name and  
         Workweek=t1.Workweek)
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but I don't think this is acceptable in SQL Server. The where clause of "Name, Workweek in" doesn't work. Am I missing something?

Comment: What is the error you got? If this doesnt work use exists

Comment: An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ','

Comment: Exists returned good results, but again, thanks for your help!

Comment: No, using two fields with an IN operator in a Where Clause doesn't work. But using EXISTS does work.